# What is the javascript convention for libraries / classes when the name starts with a number?

Tags: javascript, convention

In javascript the name of a variable can't start with a number. However, we're working under a name that starts with a number, for example, 1world. In C++ or C# I would prefix a C for a class or N for the namespace: C1world or N1world.

Is there a convention in javascript to deal with this?

Comment: I've never heard of such a case (and don't think there's a convention). Why not `OneWorld`? What's your actual name?

Comment: I don't know of one, but how about roman numerals? Something like `IWorld` or `XLIIWorld`?

Comment: Most projects have their own coding guide lines even for C++ `some_name` vs `SomeName`, `m_member` vs `member`, .... Generally the first thing is to choose a name that is easy to read and write. If I would need to write it often something like `COneWorld` would be better to me then `C1world` or `N1world` as it might result in `C!world` or `C1World` - at least it happened to me while typing right now ;)

Comment: the name is 1world. It's a public library, so trying to find the path of least surprise

Comment: i'm toying with lib1world as the public library.

Comment: Yes, that would work fine as well. Just don't use some random prefix like `N` or `C` that no one understands :-)

Answer (score 0):

All named objects in JavaScript should begin with a letter. In cases where I've wanted to begin with a number, I've simply spelled it out in camelCase, (i.e. oneMethod or OneConstructor).

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp

Comment: in this case, since it is public facing lib and part of a brand name, I want to keep the number 1 in there. I'm thinking about using lib1world

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me, and doesn't violate conventions. Go for it.